# Running an R-script while computer is on standby

Tags: r, scheduled-tasks

I'm going to be out of the office for a couple of months. I'd like to set up some R-scripts to run on a scheduled basis while I'm out. I've done this before, on my home computer, and it works fine. However, I work in healthcare, so when I'm not here, my computer is logged off in standby. How can I get my scheduled scripts to run even when my computer is not on or logged in (if I even can)? Nobody else in my department is familiar with R, so it's not feasible to have them run the scripts in my stead.

Comment: Getting jobs to run when you are logged out or your computer is locked really depends more on your operating system. There's not a whole like that would be R specific about that. It's more of a systems administration task than a programming task. You are probably better off seeking help at: https://superuser.com/

Answer (score 0):

You could consider to install the package/add-in "taskscheduleR" and make it run certain Rscripts on a regular basis on your or one of your colleagues computer. I believe it also contains an option to run scripts "ONIDLE".